# iPhone: Close Safari and return to homescreen using a script?

Tags: javascript, iphone, mobile-safari, url-scheme

I have a .html-file that loads a javascript when loaded. I use this to turn on/off electronics in my home.

Currently I have saved the link on my homescreen (iPhone), and I have set the window to close automatically after 1 second of it being opened (which is enough for my javascript to run).

However, I think it would be much more cool, if I somehow could get Safari to close after closing the window. In that way I could return to my homescreen, so I wouldn't have to touch the homebutton, and thereby using this link as a sort of "switch" on my homescreen to turn on/off my electronics.

I have thought of using some code like:

```
function redirection() {
var userAgent = window.navigator.userAgent;
if (userAgent.match(/iPad/i) || userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) {
    window.location = "myapp://"    
}
}
</script>
```

But this would require a URL Scheme for the dashboard, which I don't think exist (?).

Do you have any other suggestions or is this task just not possible to perform? :)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Apple doesn't have an approved way to exit an application, especially not one of their applications, like Safari.  Like the Hotel California, you can launch another application, but you can never leave.

Comment: Oh - and there would be no way to get the iPhone to think that I want to "launch the homescreen"? Would it make any difference if the iPhone was jailbroken - would that give me some options?

And thanks for taking the time to answer this question. :)

Comment: "Launch the home screen" is called the Springboard app.  As far as I know, there's no url scheme that will open it.  As far as jailbreaking, you're on your own there.