# Is it possible to redirect the user from a web page to the iPhone home screen?

Tags: javascript, ios

I have a web page which allows the user to download an app, this part is working.

But when the download is launched I would like to make a redirection to the home screen of the iPhone in order to show the user that the download started.

I know it's possible to redirect to an app like this :

```
window.location = "bundle.id://"
```

So the first thing I tried to achieve (with no success) is :

`window.location = "com.apple.springboard://"`

But as I said it doesn't work. So is it possible to redirect to the home screen that way ?

---

The URL I use to launch the app download is like this :

```
itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=my-app-plist-url.plist
```

So I was wondering if **itms-services** has some parameters to make the iPhone goes to the home screen where the app is installed ?

Comment: My first question would be... Why? Other than that I couldn't imagine of a way to just 'go' to the homescreen. You might want to look for workaround to close the browser. But there is no default way for you Apple suggests (or even wants).

Comment: @Akaino It's because when the download and the installation of the app are launched, it stays on the web page. And I wanted to go to the home screen in order to show the user that the download is launched

Comment: Yeah, a second after my comment I thought about something like that, too. But no. Unfortunately there is no way to do that without jailbreaking afaik. And I for one would be very sceptical if that ever happened to me as I'm very used to the browser staying open. And I think many users are.

Answer (score 1):

Not as far as I know.
Check this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14739013/iphone-close-safari-and-return-to-homescreen-using-a-script)

Apple does not have an approved way to exit their applications.